# GATE learning plugin loading error

Tags: error-handling, machine-learning, nlp, gate

I'm having some trouble loading the GATE learning plugin.  I've checked my .xml configuration file against my co-worker's whose module is able to load, and they're identical (they come directly from the GATE website's tutorial).  I've also tried re-installing gate, deleting log files, and restarting my computer.

When I try to load the learning plugin, I get the following error:

```
gate.creole.ResourceInstantiationException: 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at gate.learning.LearningAPIMain.init(LearningAPIMain.java:230)
    at gate.Factory.createResource(Factory.java:432)
    at gate.gui.NewResourceDialog$4.run(NewResourceDialog.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at gate.learning.NLPFeaturesList.loadFromFile(NLPFeaturesList.java:64)
    at gate.learning.LightWeightLearningApi.furtherInit(LightWeightLearningApi.java:97)
    at gate.learning.LearningAPIMain.init(LearningAPIMain.java:212)
    ... 3 more
```

I'm not really sure what's causing this error.  To be honest the plugin was loading earlier this week, but then it started giving me this.  I haven't been able to find anyone else with this problem, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I remember this could be related to the fact that there is no one feature defined in ML config file was produced (empty document, not tokenised, no sentences produced and etc).

Comment: Does the class you are learning from exist?